# Leaflet circle color depend on variable

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want the color of the circle in Leaflet to depend on a variable.
Current code looks like this and does not work:

```
              function displayMapLatLng
             (lat, lng, boolean,  displayInfo) {
              var latlng =
              new L.LatLng(lat, lng);

              var color =
                  if (boolean =='Y'){
                                      "blue"
                                      }else{
                                      "red"
                                      }

              var circle =
                  new L.circle ((latlng), 20, {color: 'color', opacity:.5})
                  circle.addTo(map);
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to change the fill color or stroke color?

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` statement is not valid JavaScript. You can write it as a trenary operation instead:

```
function displayMapLatLng (lat, lng, boolean,  displayInfo) {
    var latlng = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var color = (boolean === 'Y') ? "blue" : "red";

    var circle = new L.circle ((latlng), 20, {color: color, opacity:.5})
    circle.addTo(map);
}
```

`boolean` is a strange name for a string variable too. If it actually is a boolean value you can write the operation as:

```
var color = (boolean) ? "blue" : "red";
```

#### Update:

In the case where you have more possible color values a trenary operation would be less useful. Then an `if ... else if` statement or `switch` statement would be more appropriate:

```
var color;

switch(boolean) {
    case 'B':
        color = 'blue';
        break;
    case 'R':
        color = 'red';
        break;
    case 'W':
        color = 'white';
        break;
    case 'K': // as in kobolt
        color = 'black';
        break;
    default: 
        color = 'yellow';
        break;
}
```

The `default` case will be used when no other case matches `boolean`.

Comment: Choosing boolean as a string variable is indeed strange, I use a Dutch name and used the name boolean for asking the question here. The var color = boolean ? 'blue' : 'red'; solved it, thanks. –

Comment: One more question, how does this trenary operation work in case of more possible values.

E.g. B = Blue, R = Red, W= White, B = Black.

Comment: Then it wouldn't work, so good. I'll update the answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your code to choose the colour has a syntax error.

If `typeof boolean === 'string'`, try:

```
var color = boolean == 'Y' ? 'blue' : 'red';
```

But if, more logically, `typeof boolean === 'boolean'`, try:

```
var color = boolean ? 'blue' : 'red';
```